Allow local users to install and run software for specific vendors
I have a group of remote Technician that need privileges to use COM settings, Network Settings and Install and uninstall Software.
I have the Network and COM part with local Usergroups. I need a solution for the install/ uninstall part.
I have an Active Directory Domain.
I don't have a license for Intune.
I cannot use software distribution. A technician installs and uninstalls software multiple time per day.
I tested App streaming / RDP but connection isnt stable enough (remote locations), also the software needs a connection to a COM port.
I also tested HyperV VMs but the COM connection cannot be forwarded (The industrial tool cannot find a connection if the Software is running inside the VM)
I also tested Software Restriction Policy with "Basic User". Beside that the default option did not change the need for administrator privileges to start/install software.
"Basic User" isn't an Option for Certificate Rules (I want to allow a Publisher (certificate)).
If restriction for a specific Publisher isn't posible, a general install/start option would be my next best option, better than full local admin.
Im stuck at this point since most of the posts i found have only answers with "don't give permissions to install" or "use software distribution". Both things that I know but cannot use.

There isn't a separate permission for software installation.
The way some organizations do this is utilize a proxy application and user identity to install software. This can exist as a service, and usually works the same way except it is run under a different local identity that has administrator permission. It has loggin and filtering capabilities to have allowed and disallowed applications.

Thank you for the Idea.
Sadly, the Clients also missing a stable Internet connection (remote locations) and they need to connect specialized hardware via COM. We also had the idea for HyperV VMs but we where unable to forward the COM connections to the VMs.
Some single requests or auth with Azure would be a problem, application streaming is impossible.
If I have misunderstood you, please correct me.

What I described doesn't require an Internet connection.

That sounds like the perfect solution then. The only thin i can find with "proxy application and user identity" is "Microsoft Entra/Azure Application proxy".
Can you link a example or name the software?
